# Ubuntu Server 13.10 can't mount hard drive that is on my router

Tags: server, mount, fstab, router, cifs

So I am working currently with my Ubuntu server which I have it on my laptop at the moment so I can test out how to work with the server OS. I have it up and running with samba, openSSH, webmin, and plexmedia server.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the server to get to the router hard drive. I have a TP-link wdr3500. The format of the hard drive is a FAT32.

What I've tried:
install cifs.

`sudo vi /etc/fstab`

Type out `\\ \tplinklogin.net\volume1 \mnt\media cifs guest 0 0`

I have also tried out `\\\192.168.0.1\volume1 \mnt\media cifs guest 0 0`

But then when I go to terminal and do `sudo mount -a`, I usually get a error saying wrong `fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //ipaddress/dns/volume1 , missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

But in dmesg it will say unable to determine destination address. So am I doing something wrong here? I can't install the hard drive on to my laptop since my family is constantly using it to transfer data back and forth on it and they get mad at me if I just take it away.

Answer (score 35):

I have figured it out. Apparently I didn't have `cifs-utils` installed onto my server. Everything is working now.

Install it by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Comment: It should be accepted answer for sure.

Comment: Should actually be on Serverfault since it isn't Ubuntu-specific. I was able to fix the same issue on RHEL7 with this answer.